# Java 8 How to get a some elements out of a list with parameters from a nother list

Tags: java, jpa, java-8, java-stream

I am not sure if someone ask it before. How can I get all User form the following list where the rightId is equal 30 for example.

User Object:

```
public class User {   
    private int id;   
    private String email;

    private List<Rights> RightsSet;
}
```

User Rights:

```
public class Rights{
    private int id;
    private String Name;

    private List<User> userSet;
}
```

The relation is a ManyToMany and I use JPA. But I won't use a namedQuery or other SQL statements.

I tried this:

```
List<User> userList = em2.getAllEntity(User.class); //I get all User
1.
List<User>o = userList.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getRightsSet().stream()
                    .anyMatch(y -> y.getId() == 5201)
                    )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
2. 
List<User> rights = userList.stream()
               .filter(x -> x.getRightsSet().stream()
                        .filter(y -> y.getId() == 31).findAny().orElse(null) != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with the above approach?

Comment: y.getId() == 31 and  y.getId() == 5201 are should be  y.getId() == 30

Comment: Do you want to filter using another list of elements?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I always get all users and not only with the rightId = 30

Comment: i want to have all users with the rightid = 30

Comment: @JanBraunsdorff "i want to have all users with the rightid = 30" then why are you comparing with `5201` and `31`?. ultimately, it's unclear what you want at the moment. consider updating your post to clarify and give examples if possible.

Comment: I don't see any issue in your 1st approach however.